# Why didn't everybody apply to become a carer in Never Let Me Go?

Tags: never-let-me-go

Every donor shown seemed to be aware of his or her fate. They also wanted to avoid or delay that fate and thus the desire for deferrals was present. There was also an option to apply for becoming a carer which would delay the donations of that donor by several years. Why didn't everybody want to become a carer?

I've already checked this [link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/why-didnt-the-characters-rebel-or-run-in-never-let-me-go) and that doesn't answer my question. They didn't run or rebel because they couldn't (possibly) think of such a choice. But the choice to become a carer was open to everybody. It wasn't restricted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all clones became carers first and then donors. They would leave the cottages, become carers and then become donors. There is a part Ruth mentions that some don't do well as carers and so just give up and apply early to begin their donations. This was because they couldn't take the endless cycle of watching their patients die and knowing that is what was headed for them. What made a 'good' carer like Ruth who was able to go so long as a carer was that she could take it and deal (well, she was mostly passive), but not all clones could take it being carers for that long.